# Why does htop show more threads than puma configuration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, puma

My puma configuration:

```
#!/usr/bin/env puma

workers ENV.fetch("WEB_CONCURRENCY") { 2 }
threads_count = ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 }
threads threads_count, threads_count
worker_timeout 30

preload_app!

port ENV['PORT'] || 80
environment ENV['RAILS_ENV'] || 'development'
rackup      DefaultRackup

before_fork do
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.disconnect! if defined?(ActiveRecord)
end

on_worker_boot do
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection if defined?(ActiveRecord)
end
```

The htop:

[image]

The number of threads should be 5, but the htop shows that there are 12 threads in each worker(process). BTW, I run the workers and htop in a docker container.

That confused me a lot, could somebody explain it?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/145707/why-doesnt-htop-display-the-same-processes-as-top and https://askubuntu.com/questions/17047/in-htop-i-sometimes-see-lists-of-64-processes-identical-for-all-but-the-pid-w

Comment: You can read more about puma [thread pool](https://github.com/puma/puma#thread-pool) - puma can create threads for internal purposes.